# Postfix - User unknown in virtual mailbox table + authentification failed

Tags: postfix, courier

I'm trying to set postfix with MySQL authentication. I can send mails (from postfixadmin) to different domains. The problem is that I cannot send any mail to my domain or even log-in to squirrelMail even if I've created new user in postfixadmin.

When I send an email to my domain it logs an error:

```
Jan 31 10:47:17 server postfix/proxymap[4534]: warning: table "mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf": empty lookup result for: "domain.tld" -- ignored
Jan 31 10:47:17 server postfix/smtpd[4533]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from nat-simple12.ntkcz.de[195.113.241.228]: 550 5.1.1 <test@domain.tld>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<test@workround.org> to=<test@domain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<workaround.org>
```

If I try to login to squirrelMail it logs:

```
Jan 31 11:15:42 server imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=test@domain.tld, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Jan 31 11:15:47 server imapd: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], rcvd=54, sent=332
```

my /etc/postfix/main.cf contains:

```
...
# my configuration
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_mailbox_extended = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf
...
```

I can't find any problem in my configuration. Does anybody see any problem or any direction I can move forward because I'm completely stuck.

Thanks,
Mateo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Jan 31 10:47:17 server postfix/proxymap[4534]: warning: table "mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf": empty lookup result for: "domain.tld" -- ignored
```

That line is the first thing you need to solve. For some reason Postfix thinks that domain does not exist. I suspect that Postfixadmin is working correctly and you've entered the right domain, but you have a typo in /etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf that is causing the lookup of the domain to fail.

Comment: I think that this warning is just an information. In "mysql_relay_domains_maps.cf" I have this query "query = SELECT d.description FROM domain AS d WHERE d. = '%s'". If I change the SELECT clause to "Select d.domain ...' it logs: "warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains". Nevertheless these warnings are logged only if I send an email from postfixadmin. The login problem still holds...:-(

Comment: If Postfix can't deliver an email, the .maildir/ for the user won't be created. If the user does not have a maildir then various imap daemons do odd things. IIRC older versions of Courier would not log you in without a maildir. In any case if you're trying to get imap to work the problem is not in your Postfix config.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed in my Courier not in postfix. I had a mistype in my /etc/courier/authdaemonrc. Where line

```
authmodulelist="authmysql"
```

was

```
authmodulelist="autmysql"
```